# C-compiler in C

Tags: arduino

I want to load a C-program to a Arduino, enter
some C-commands via Serial, and enter "Run" and then the program should be run. Is this possible? Is there a Library? Thank you very much!

Comment: As the answers pointed - you want an interpreter. And, since it is interpreter, you better do it not for the C syntax, but something simpler/more dedicated to the specific tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called an interpreter, which executes as you get the code. An example one for Arduino is:

http://n.mtng.org/ele/arduino/iarduino.html

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want some C interpreter. You might find some (e.g. [Ch](https://www.softintegration.com/)), but it is unlikely they have been  ported to Arduino.

The Arduino is really a cheap and slow micro controller (without much RAM). It is not reasonable to run a compiler or some complex interpreter on the Arduino itself.

You might read more about compilers & interpreters and implement a tiny interpreter running on the Arduino.

You'll better switch to Raspberry Pi. It is powerful enough to run an interpreter, and even a compiler.

Comment: Considering 80ies homecomputers had actually less computational power and a lot of them had even less RAM (e.g. ZX81), using an interpreter is not really a problem. However, it possibly should just be for a simpler syntax/grammar than C.